# Vertical Scaling with Terraform

Tags: cluster-computing, digital-ocean, terraform

I am using [terraform](https://www.terraform.io/) to set up a VPS Cluster.

This works already pretty well. I have defined a `variable` called `instance_size` which is set to `1gb` by default. I am setting up several VPS with the exact same configuration by using the `count` parameter within my `resource` definition:

```
variable "swarm_instance_size" {
    default = "1gb"
}

resource "digitalocean_droplet" "server" {
    image = "123456"
    size = "${var.instance_size}"
    count = "3"
    name = "${format("server-%02d", (count.index + 1))}"
    region = "sfc1"
}
```

*(Excluded SSH Keys and Provisioners for Brevity)*

**My Question is now how to best vertically scale only a single one of those ressources.**

I am able to scale all of them without downtime by increasing the `instance_size` to for example `2gb` and executing `terraform apply --parallelism 1` so that only a single resource gets updated at a time.

I can as well target only a single one of those ressources by using `terraform apply -target digitalocean_droplet.server[0] -var instance_size=2gb`. The problem is that this leads to unexpected configuration drift as I haven't declared that change anywhere else than when executing the command.

Is the only and best way to declare each one of those servers as a single resource ommiting the count parameter? And than if I want to add a new server instead of increasing the count parameter I just add another resource definition to my terraform config?

Comment: version control your codes, before you `terraform apply`

Comment: @BMW this doesn't really make sense. If I change the swarm_instance_size to say 2gb I will scale all instances of that ressources and not just a single one. So version control doesn't solves the problem/question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using a [map](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html#maps)

For example (this goes in your variables.tf file):

```
variable "machines" {
  description = "description here"
  type = "map"
  default = {
    "server-01" = 1gb
    "server-02" = 1gb
    "server-03" = 2gb
  }
}
```

Then in your actual code:

```
size = ${lookup(var.machines, format("server-%02d", (count.index + 1)))}
```

You can then apply the plan.

Comment: works. Just forgot the leading zeroes :) thanks a lot! wasn't able to find this anywhere